# How to keep decimal accuracy when dividing with floating points

Tags: math, floating-point, division

I am working on a project, and I need to divide a very large 64 bit `long` value. I absolutely do not care about the whole number result, and only care about the decimal value. The problem is that when dividing a large `long` with a small 64 bit `double` floating point value, I loose accuracy in the floating point value due to it needing to store the whole numbers.

Essentially what I am trying to do is this:

```
double x = long_value / double_value % 1;
```

but without loosing precision the larger the `long_value` is. Is there a way of writing this expression so that the whole numbers are discarded and floating point accuracy is not lost? Thanks.

EDIT: btw im out here trying to upvote all these helpful answers, but I just made this account for this question and `you need 15 reputation to cast a vote`

Comment: Please tag this with what language you're using. BTW be prepared for an answer of "don't use floating point"

Comment: Specify what you need in the way of the “decimal value”. When dividing 1 by 3, the result is ⅓, which has no terminating decimal value; it requires .33333…, with the digits going on forever. If you want a decimal result, then it necessarily must be inexact in these case. How inexact can it be; how much accuracy do you need? Or did you write “decimal value” to mean the fractional part? If so, then in what form do you need the fractional part? Would returning an integer numerator and an integer denominator suffice, such as 1 and 3 for 1/3 (or for 4/3, 7/3, and so on)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @EricPostpischil. I didn't realize that discrepancy. I am looking to get a floating point value out at the end, so my accuracy lies within the limits of floating point values in general.

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe say your float value is p/q where p/q is the exact rational equivalent of the float, then you have L/(p/q) where L is your long. So what you are looking for is ((L times q) mod p)/p. My grasp of this stuff is weak, but it seems plausible you can compute the numerator (L times q) mod p without computing L times q. Maybe someone else can address that.

Comment: Separate `long_value` into its high 32 bits (including 32 bits of trailing zeros) and its low 32 bits, called `x1` and `x0`. Then `x1` and `x0` will convert to `double` with no error (assuming `double` is the ubiquitous IEEE-754 binary64). Then `fmod(x1, double_value)` and `fmod(x0, double_value)` give the remainders with no error. You can add those, take the `fmod` again, and divide by `double_value` to have the fractional part with very little error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your language provides an exact `fmod` implementation you can do something like this:

```
double rem = fmod(long_value, double_value);
return rem / double_value;
```

If `long_value` does not convert exactly to a `double` value, you could split it into two halves, `fmod` them individually, add these values together and divide that sum or `sum - double_value` by `double_value`.

If `long_value` or `double_value` is negative you may also need to consider different cases depending on how your `fmod` behaves and what result you expect.

Comment: This was the one. I knew there might be a simple thing I was overlooking. My language allowed me to write it like this `double x = long_value % double_value / double_value`. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`long_value` is congruent to:

```cpp
long_value = long_value - double_value * static_cast<long>(long_value / double_value);
```

Then you can do this:

```cpp
double fractionalPart = static_cast<double>(long_value / double_value) % 1;
```

Comment: If `long_value` is very large (e.g., near its maximum) and `double_value` is small (e.g., less than 1), the division you're using is going to result in overflow and you're going to at best lose accuracy or, worse, crash or get a wrong result.

Comment: @params The values for `long_value` and `double_value` are so that the division does not overflow, but instead result in a valid double-precision float. However, because this `double` has to allocate a lot of bits to the whole number part, it does not leave enough bits for the decimal parts, that he is interested in.

Comment: My solution is to reduce the `long_value` such that the decimal answer remains the same, but effectively has only one bit used for the whole number part, leaving the other bits for the decimal part, increasing precision.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't simply reduce `long_value` to something congruent, because in order to reduce it you perform a division of the original `long_value` by a small `double`. This has a chance of failure because the quotient may be larger than what a `long` can contain. Try your code with the max positive value for `long_value` and 0.5 for `double_value` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You are correct that if `abs(double_value) > 0 && abs(double_value) < 1`, and `long_value` is bigger than half of MAX_LONG_INT_VALUE, the division will overflow. Ofcourse, my answer assumes that such extreme cases do not happen, which is areasonable assumption since OP mentions that results are correct but not precise.

Comment: I see. I think it best to assume that those cases _could_ happen, since OP mentions a "very large" `long` and a "small" `double`.

Comment: This may not be completely off base. Its reasonable in my situation to not let `double_value` go below 1.

Comment: While this was a really good answer theoretically, it would leave a bit of periodic errors while the long value increased. Thanks for your input though @akaAbdullahMateen

Answer (score 0):

Does the language you're using have a big integer/big rational library? To avoid loss of information, you'll have to "spread out" the information across more memory while you're transforming it so you don't lose the part you're interested in preserving. This is essentially what a big integer library would do for you. You could employ this algorithm (I don't know what language you're using so this is just pseudocode:

```
// e.g. 1.5 => (3, 2)
let (numerator, denominator) = double_value.ToBigRational().NumAndDenom();

// information-preserving version of long_value / double_value
let quotient = new BigRational(num: long_value * denominator, denom: numerator);

// information-preserving version of % 1
let remainder = quotient.FractionPart();

// some information could be lost here, but we saved it for the last step
return remainder.ToDouble();
```

Comment: I am almost confident that he is either using C or C++. In either case, he can go with GMP, but I do not think he wants to do that. Since, setting it up requires a bit of GMP specific knowledge.

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for. I will explore this route. I am currently working in C#, but using the Unity Engine and burst compiler so there is a lot of weird language requirements, so worst case I implement it myself. Thanks again, ill update if this is works.